# Matlab fminsearch Error : Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 72-by-1

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, coefficients, fminsearch

I am trying to do a curve fitting using Matlab `fminsearch`.

Here is what I wrote :

```
Idata = readtable('Data_batterie.xlsx','Sheet','C(T)','Range','A1:A72');
Idata = table2array(Idata);
Tdata = readtable('Data_batterie.xlsx','Sheet','C(T)','Range','B1:B72');
Tdata = table2array(Tdata);
Cdata = readtable('Data_batterie.xlsx','Sheet','C(T)','Range','E1:E72');
Cdata = table2array(Cdata);

I = Idata
T = Tdata
C = Cdata

Capa = @(x)x(1).*(T+x(2))./(T+x(3)).*(x(4)+x(5).*I)+(x(6)+x(7).*atan(x(8)+x(9).*I))-C;
%x(1) --> x(9) = a1 --> i1

x0 = [ 1.35803674e+00  6.26544343e+00  5.64908765e+00  4.22139110e+01 7.09357003e-01 -3.03109514e+01 -2.97030786e+00 -2.35995343e-01 1.13629716e-02];
bestx = fminsearch(Capa,x0)
```

Unfortunately, I encounter the error mentionned in the title when I try to run it but I don't know what is my error here.

It probably is a simple syntax error but I can't seem to find it

I'm trying to find the values of the x coefficients, but the problem is that I can't run the `fminsearch`.

I tried to swap some values of the functions but the error stays the same

Comment: Wolfie seems to have found your problem, but in general it is better to copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace. All that information in the error message that you didn't include in your post is very useful to figure out where it comes from and why.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the function `Capa` outputs an array the same size as `T`, `I`, and `C`, i.e. 72x1.

`fminsearch` is trying to minimise a scalar-valued function. Maybe you want to change `Capa` to something like `Capa = @(x)norm( ____ )` or some other function to generate a scalar output which should be minimised instead of an array.

From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html):

> `fun`: fun is a function that accepts a vector or array `x` **and returns a real scalar** `f`